# Data type mismatch in criteria expression | Access, OleDb, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, datetime, oledb

I read/update data from MS Access using C#.
My code is:

```
public static void UpdateLastLogin(int userid, DateTime logintime) ///logintime = DateTime.Now
{
    string sql = @"UPDATE [Customers] SET [LastLogin]=?";
    OleDbParameter[] prms = new OleDbParameter[] { 
     new OleDbParameter("@LastLogin",logintime)
    };
    using (DAL dal = new DAL())
    {
        dal.UpdateRow(sql, false, prms);
    }
}
```

When it comes to Dates, I having trouble.
This throws a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." error.
(I removed WHERE clause for keeping it simpler)
Am I suuposed to enclose [LastLogin]=? question mark with single quotes, # signs .. does not help. 
Any leads on how to handle DateTime objects with Access and OleDb provider will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code bit would be easier to read. if you format it as code by indenting it 4 spaces

Answer (score 5):

There is a known issue with OleDb and dates. Try doing something like:

```
OleDbParameter p = parameter as OleDbParameter;
if (null == p)
  parameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
else
  p.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date;
```

Or use explicit format string:

```
value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the following code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("datenow", OleDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["datenow"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no your SQL statement should be:

```
"UPDATE Customers SET LastLogin=@LastLogin"
```

Secondly, the reason you are receiving the date mismatch error will probably be your passing '?' as your date time into the LastLogin field instead of the actual logintime parameter.

Comment: But this is access .. I tought oleDb does not support named parameter :(

Comment: The above statement should be ok assuming you are using an OleDbCommand

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ' ' + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

instead, pass it as String (and maybe enclose with # then)

Comment: Maybe a format string passed to ToString() of DateTime will help

Comment: edited my post ... should work. There maybe more elegant ways to do it, since this could possibly depend on your localization options though ...

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

```
"UPDATE Customers SET LastLogin='@LastLogin'"
```

And @LastLogin should be

```
logintime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

*edit*
Could you not just inline the whole thing?

```
"UPDATE Customers SET LastLogin='" + logintime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "'"
```

Comment: You could inline the whole thing, yes, but creating dynamic sql is a bad habit to get into. 
Using a parameter is better design and just as easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "DBTYPE" property of the parameter to identify it as a date, datetime or datetime2 as appropriate...

```
prms[0].DbType = DbType.DateTime;
```

There are 7 signatures to the new OleDbParameter() call, so you may change the signature instance, or just do explicitly as I sampled above since you only had 1 parameter in this case.