# Problem with inserting date to Ms-Access database

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have in my `Ms-Access` database table, a date field in Short Date format.

I have in my C# program `DateTimePicker` control in `dd/MM/yyyy`  `short` date format

I try to insert data using C# code like this:

```
SQL = "insert into MyTbl(D_from,D_to) values (@MyFrom,@MyTo)";
OleDbCommand Cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
OleDbParameter dateparam1 = Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyFrom", DbType.DateTime);
dateparam1.Value = dt_From.Value; 

OleDbParameter dateparam2 = Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTo", DbType.DateTime);
dateparam2.Value = dt_To.Value;

Cmd.CommandText = SQL;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and I got the error: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Answer (score 2):

change Parameters.AddWithValue to Parameters.Add

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyFrom", DbType.DateTime);
```

if you use `Parameters.AddWithValue` then you need to pass the `Value` as Second `Parameter`, not the DataType

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyFrom", dt_From.Value);
```

and also you need to set the `CommandType` as `Text`

Comment: OleDbCommand Cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyFrom", dt_From.Value);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTo", dt_To.Value);
Cmd.CommandText = SQL;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question

[Data type mismatch in criteria expression | Access, OleDb, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577901/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-access-oledb-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dateparam1.Value = dt_From.Value.ToShortDateString();
dateparam2.Value = dt_To.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Otherwise have look at this :

Date values must be either delimited according to the ODBC canonical date format or delimited by the datetime delimiter ("#"). Otherwise, Microsoft Access will treat the value as an arithmetic expression and will not raise a warning or error.

For example, the date "March 5, 1996" must be represented as {d '1996-03-05'} or #03/05/1996#; otherwise, if only 03/05/1993 is submitted, Microsoft Access will evaluate this as 3 divided by 5 divided by 1996. This value rounds up to the integer 0, and since the zero day maps to 1899-12-31, this is the date used.

A pipe character (|) cannot be used in a date value, even if enclosed in back quotes.